# How to echo SUM value of SQL list

Tags: php, sql

I have this SQL list:

[image]

I am interested to echo the total amount of the list `product_quantity` so it says `301`

[image]

```
//total
$this->tbl_inventory('product_quantity');
$data['total_quantity'] = count($this->global_model->get());
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images, which can't be copied, searched, and which offer poor accessibility. Instead, copy and paste into the question box and format it as code using the `{}` button or by pressing Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->tbl_inventory('product_quantity');
$data['total_quantity'] = sum($this->global_model->get());
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.